# How to show custom checkout filed in admin panel

Tags: magento, module, magento2

How to display custom column in the admin panel.

Tables `sales_order`, `quote`, column name `gst`.

I want to display a column in the sale order.

Code details

[click here](https://github.com/nkscoder/custom_field_gst_in_checkout-)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFAlf.png)

Comment: Frontend is working fine but issues only admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the adminhtml template file "order/view/info.phtml" and add the code to display your GST below billing address section. Refer below code sample.

**app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Add below code to your info.phtml to the section below billing address (DON'T REPLACE THE ENTIRE CONTENT).

**app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getOrder()->getGst();?>
```

Comment: Thanks Nidheesh, but remove all old functionality  display only **GST**

Comment: I want to both old order details and gst

Comment: @NiteshKumarSingh you mean you are only seeing the GST value and not any other contents like order details etc? If that's the case, probably you have replaced the content of info.phtml. Please call the snippet I mentioned below the billing address section in info.phtml